# Attempting to fix w3 validator error and warning

Tags: html, css, validation

When testing my html code in the `W3 validator`, I was given this error and warning message:

Line 21, Column 23: The first occurrence of `ID menuItem` was here.

```
<li id="menuItem"><a href="#visit">Ten Places to Visit</a></li>
```

✉
 Line 29, Column 25: Duplicate ID menuItem.

```
<li id="menuItem"><a href="#Wrigley">Wrigley Field</a></li>
```

However, when I try removing the `id=""` part of the tag, so it reads `<li menuItem>` I lose the attributes of `menuItem`.

Should this type of error from the validator typically be ignored, or am I not correcting it properly?

Comment: post the w3c link of the validation page

Comment: Nobody here can read minds (at least I think so). Post some code!

Comment: Ids need to be unique for your html to be valid(and validate), what you are doing with ids should be done with classes `<li class="menuItem" menuItem>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using same id multiple times is not valid. Try to use `class` instead of `id` (If you are using id to call only style)

Comment: Thank you. I took your suggestion and all the errors pertaining to my question went away. btw. here's the link: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F101818591%2FNEIU%2FCS412_WebAppDevelopment%2FAssignment2%2FGutstein_Homework2.html

Comment: I can see there is an error still which is for adding ul after the li closing tag. you cant add anything between two li. Always add the child items inside the li, like <li class="menuItem"><a href="#builingInfo">About Each Building/Site</a> <ul><li>...</li></ul>  </li>

Comment: I did that and then lost all the properties of the nested <ul>. Does that require another piece of css, such as .menuItem ul li ?

Answer (score 0):

The ID menuitem has repeated on the same page. So change make the ID as unique.

In W3 validator ID should be unique.

You can change the code like this.

```
<li id="menuItem0"><a href="#visit">Ten Places to Visit</a></li>
<li id="menuItem1"><a href="#Wrigley">Wrigley Field</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the W3 Validator is right to have complained! You cannot use the same ID name twice, if you do use it twice, you will ebd up overwriting the other item. W3 validator always track for all these to maintain website standard and integrity. Therefore, you will need to use unique ID name identifier for each reference. Try this:

```
<li id="menuItem"><a href="#visit">Ten Places to Visit</a></li>
<li id="menuItemA"><a href="#Wrigley">Wrigley Field</a></li>
```

I hope this helps.